# Why did the ring need to have a bearer?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, the-fellowship-of-the-ring

Why not put it in a box or something and take the box to Mount Doom?

Comment: And who indeed would take it? And wouldn't they be, in fact, the Ringbearer?

Comment: Aah, thank you. Yes I think someone would indeed take the ring for himself (Boromir), but they never talk about changing ringbearer or not having a ringbearer at all.

Comment: Without a ringbearer, the ring couldn't go anywhere, which would kind of shoot down the idea of getting it destroyed in a foreign land. :-)

Comment: that could have used bill the pony and he could have been the ring bearer :D

Comment: Just because the pony is *carrying* the ring doesn't mean he's *the Ringbearer*. The Ringbearer is the one who, like Frodo or Sam, assumes responsibility for the ring.

Comment: the pony can assume responsibility!

Comment: @Himarm The pony is a rational being?

Comment: If mlp is any example, then no, the pony is not rational under the influence of magic. @gutting

Comment: @Tolkien501 - Short answer:  The person carrying the box would be the Ringbearer.

Answer (score 8):

Being a ring bearer doesn't mean you have to wear the ring, or even carry it around in your hand. It simply means you are the person who possesses the ring, who's in control of it at any given time. If you had put the ring in a box, and put the box in a saddle bag, whoever was riding or leading the horse would be the ring bearer.

Note that, for most of the trip, Frodo's carrying the ring on a chain around his neck; that's not significantly different from having it in his pocket in a ring box. No matter where the ring is, the ring bearer could *go get it* and put it on, if they were tempted.

There are a few periods where the ring has no bearer; for example, it spends a lot of time at the bottom of a lake before Smeagol finds it, and it spends a bit of time on the cave floor before Bilbo finds it. However, the ring can't move by itself in those cases: some conscious entity has to find it and pick it up for it to go anywhere.

*Best case*, we might imagine a scenario where the ring was put in a box in a bigger box on a sled, and 3-4 people all collectively pull the sled; it's not clear if any of those people could be considered ring bearers at that point. But, ultimately, if any one of those people were sufficiently tempted by the ring, they could just snatch it and run off with it. (As we've seen, the ring is capable of affecting even those people that aren't currently carrying it; it basically drove Boromir insane just walking near Frodo for long enough.)

Answer (score 2):

Adding to Edenfields answer:

- A box has the disadvantage that it needs a pocket or a backpack. This
  allows stealing the ring or losing the ring (the backpack laces are
  breaking or you need to flee after an assault and forget your backpack).
  By using a necklace it is guaranteed that someone who wants to steal
  the ring needs to touch the Ringbearer.
- The ring is evil and actively tries to escape. During the talk with Gandalf
  Frodo recounts that the ring is able to change its diameter and slip off.
  It is heavily implied that the ring betrayed Isildur by giving off a
  treacherous glint while swimming. He slipped off Gollum's finger
  to be found. And remember: At no time Boromir had contact with the ring
  and the ring was out of sight most of the time and *still* the ring was
  able to poison his mind. I do not think a box would change the fact.

In fact the necklace is really a very good idea to guarantee that the ring
cannot escape and that it cannot be lost or stolen.